# Accessing OpenCV Mat elements gives wrong results

Tags: opencv, matrix

I am new to OpenCV and am a little bit confused how to access MAt in the right way.

I have two IplImages revA and revB. I create to new Mat with their data and compare those matrices and try to save the difference in the Mat r. Now I need to know, where the differences are.

My try:

```
revA=cvLoadImage(argv[1], 1);
revB=cvLoadImage(argv[2],1);

IplImage* changeMap = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(revA), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 

cv::Mat a(revA);
cv::Mat b(revB);
cv::Mat r(changeMap);

cv::compare(a, b, r, CV_CMP_EQ);
imshow( "changes", r);
```

I see that there ARE differences in the window, they also look right, but when I try to do something like the following code, I never find a value that is not 255...

```
for(int i=0; i<r.rows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<r.cols; j++){ 
        cv::Vec3b c = r.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0);
        if(c[0] != 255 || c[1] != 255 || c[2] != 255){
            printf("%d %d %d\n", c[0], c[1], c[2]);  
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody figure out, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: also, if I inspect the Mat by using cout << r I clearly see that there are not only 255 values

Comment: Well, it looks like you're always accessing (0, 0) instead of (i, j) within the loop, for one.

Comment: Also since r is an 8-bit 1-channel array it doesn't make sense to access the values as Vec3b.

Comment: Ähm... damn. I wish the ground would open and swallow me up. Thanks, did'nt see it for hours... :-/

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone. That's why fresh eyes on code often helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you are trying to access the `Mat` as if it were a 3-channel image, but you clearly loaded the `IplImage` as grayscale, i.e. single channel, so you need to do something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<r.rows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<r.cols; j++){
        float pixel = r.at<float>(i,j);
    }
}
```

The second problem was already fixed in the code above, but you were always accessing the pixel at index `0,0` instead of `i,j` at every iteration of the loop. Hehe